# Match sequenced values in a row and a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a row that has cargo weight:

| Weight 1 | Weight 2 | Weight 3 | Weight 4 | Weight 5 | Weight 6 | Weight 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 6 | 0 | 9 | 0 | 9 | 0 |

And a column that has the costs for it:

| Costs |
| --- |
| 3595.11 |
| 4437.08 |
| 4939.34 |

The smallest cost matches the smallest cargo weight, the medium cost matches the medium cargo weight and so on. But these values are copied from another sheet so they are variable.

I'd like to have a function under the cargo weight row that matches the values as I explained in the line above and excludes zero. Does anyone know how it could be done?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What code have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: I haven't tried a code, for I believe it could possibly be done with a formula. I've tried with the SMALL and MAX/MIN functions but they won't work with the values in the middle of the maximum and minimum values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one has Office 365:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SORT($J$2:$J$4,,-1),MATCH(A2,SORT(UNIQUE($A$2:$G$2,TRUE),1,-1,TRUE),0)),0)
```

[image]